# Authentication error when connecting a JavaEE MDB to a IBM MQ that shouldn't need any authentication

Tags: java, docker, ibm-mq

I have a IBM MQ (v9.2.4.0) running in a Docker container which is configured to work without authentication. However, I'm getting the following error when trying to connect with a MDB:

```
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSSecurityException: 
JMSWMQ2013: The security authentication was not valid that was supplied for queue manager 'QMGR' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'queue-test-container(1414)'.
Please check if the supplied username and password are correct on the queue manager to which you are connecting.  For further information, review the queue manager error logs and the Securing IBM MQ topic within IBM Documentation.
```

For completeness, here is its Dockerfile of the IBM MQ:

```
FROM ibmcom/mq

ENV LICENSE=accept
ENV MQ_QMGR_NAME=QMGR

COPY config.mqsc /etc/mqm/
COPY authentication.mqsc /etc/mqm/
COPY setup.sh /etc/mqm/
USER root
RUN chmod +x /etc/mqm/setup.sh

EXPOSE 1414 9443
CMD ["/etc/mqm/setup.sh"]
```

with `setup.sh` being

```
#!/bin/bash

# Apply configuration
runmqsc < /etc/mqm/config.mqsc

# Start MQ server
QMGR_NAME=$MQ_QMGR_NAME
strmqm $QMGR_NAME

runmqsc $QMGR_NAME < /etc/mqm/authentication.mqsc
```

and `config.mqsc` being

```
DEFINE QLOCAL('MY.QUEUE') REPLACE

DEFINE CHANNEL(MY.CHANNEL) +
   CHLTYPE(SVRCONN) +
   TRPTYPE(TCP) +
   MCAUSER('') +
   REPLACE
```

and `authentication.mqsc` being

```
ALTER QMGR CHLAUTH(DISABLED)
```

This should set up my queue with queue manager `QMGR`, channel `MY.CHANNEL`, queue `MY.QUEUE` and no necessary authentication on port 1414 of my docker container which runs under the name `queue-test-container`.
I already confirmed that the queue is up and running and `DISPLAY QMGR CHLAUTH CONNAUTH` also confirms that authentication is disabled for `QMGR`:

```
AMQ8408I: Display Queue Manager details.
   QMNAME(QMGR)                            CHLAUTH(DISABLED)
   CONNAUTH(DEV.AUTHINFO)
```

Now I'm having a second Docker container, containing a Java EE app that has a message driven bean connecting to the queue. I configured the MDB as follows:

```
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "useJNDI", propertyValue = "true"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "connectionNameList", propertyValue = "queue-test-container(1414)"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "queueManager", propertyValue = "QMGR"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "channel", propertyValue = "MY.CHANNEL"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "${jms.dest.queue.request.jndi}"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "transportType", propertyValue = "CLIENT"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge")})
@ResourceAdapter(value = "wmq.jmsra.rar")
```

And finally, here is the IBM MQ configuration in my standalone.xml:

```
    <system-properties>
        <property name="jms.queue.container.name" value="queue-test-container"/>
        <property name="jms.queue.container.port" value="1414"/>
        <property name="jms.connectionfactory.jndi" value="java:/ConnectionFactory"/>
        <property name="jms.dest.queue.oneway.jndi" value="java:/queue/importOnewayQueue"/>
        <property name="jms.queue.manager.channel" value="MY.CHANNEL"/>
        <property name="jms.queue.manager.connectionNameList" value="queue-test-container(1414)"/>
        <property name="jms.queue.manager.name" value="QMGR"/>
        <property name="com.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings" value="false"/>
        <property name="jms.queue.oneway" value="MY.QUEUE"/>
    </system-properties>
...
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:6.0">
            <resource-adapters>
                    <resource-adapter id="wmq.jmsra.rar">
                        <archive>
                            wmq.jmsra.rar
                        </archive>
                        <transaction-support>XATransaction</transaction-support>
                        <config-property name="reconnectionRetryCount">864</config-property>
                        <connection-definitions>
                            <connection-definition class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl" jndi-name="${jms.connectionfactory.jndi}" use-java-context="false" pool-name="connection-definition">
                                <config-property name="hostName">${jms.queue.container.name}</config-property>
                                <config-property name="port">${jms.queue.container.port}</config-property>
                                <config-property name="queueManager">${jms.queue.manager.name}</config-property>
                                <config-property name="channel">${jms.queue.manager.channel}</config-property>
                                <config-property name="transportType">CLIENT</config-property>
                                <config-property name="connectionNameList">${jms.queue.manager.connectionNameList}</config-property>
                                <recovery/>
                            </connection-definition>
                        </connection-definitions>
                        <admin-objects>
                            <admin-object class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.MQQueueProxy" jndi-name="${jms.dest.queue.oneway.jndi}" enabled="true" use-java-context="false" pool-name="OnewayQueuePool">
                                <config-property name="baseQueueName">${jms.queue.oneway}</config-property>
                                <config-property name="baseQueueManagerName">${jms.queue.manager.name}</config-property>
                            </admin-object>
                        </admin-objects>
                    </resource-adapter>
            </resource-adapters>
        </subsystem>
```

Any idea what went wrong? I'm using the version 9.2.4.0 in my pom (the same as my deployed ressource adapter), so it shouldn't be a version mismatch.

edit: here is the relevant part of my AMQERR01.LOG:

```
09/05/23 07:54:23 - Process(192.15) User(root) Program(amqzlaa0)
                    Host(332ec93769f7) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(9.2.4.0) QMgr(QMGR)
                    Time(2023-09-05T07:54:23.352Z)
                    CommentInsert1(jboss)
                    CommentInsert2(QMGR [qmgr])
                    CommentInsert3(connect)

AMQ8077W: Entity 'jboss' has insufficient authority to access object QMGR
[qmgr].

EXPLANATION:
The specified entity is not authorized to access the required object. The
following requested permissions are unauthorized: connect
ACTION:
Ensure that the correct level of authority has been set for this entity against
the required object, or ensure that the entity is a member of a privileged
group.
----- amqzfubx.c : 1640 -------------------------------------------------------
09/05/23 07:54:23 - Process(257.5) User(root) Program(amqrmppa)
                    Host(332ec93769f7) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(9.2.4.0) QMgr(QMGR)
                    Time(2023-09-05T07:54:23.352Z)
                    ArithInsert1(2) ArithInsert2(2035)
                    CommentInsert1(jboss)

AMQ9557E: Queue Manager User ID initialization failed for 'jboss'.

EXPLANATION:
The call to initialize the User ID 'jboss' failed with CompCode 2 and Reason
2035. If an MQCSP block was used, the User ID in the MQCSP block was ''. If a
userID flow was used, the User ID in the UID header was '' and any CHLAUTH
rules applied prior to user adoption were evaluated case-sensitively against
this value.
ACTION:
Correct the error and try again.
----- cmqxrsrv.c : 2619 -------------------------------------------------------
```

So I'm reading this that my JBoss container somehow uses "jboss" as a user ID, but I'm not sure how, or why this is a problem here?

Comment: `CHLAUTH(DISABLED)` turns off channel authentication. To check if CONNAUTH is disabled you would need to run DIS `AUTHINFO(DEV.AUTHINFO)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following I assume you know that this will not be a suitable production setup. You will need to assure client authentication either by userId/pw check, personal certificates, your own implementation via a security exit or what so ever. I assume you know that switching off userId/pw check means that, well userId and password won't be checked.

If you don't want any user ID and password checking at all, then set `CONNAUTH` to blank. Update your version of `authentication.mqsc`:

```
ALTER QMGR CHLAUTH(DISABLED) CONNAUTH(' ')
REFRESH SECURITY TYPE(CONNAUTH)
```

The refresh is necessary when you alter the connauth parameter and don't want to restart the Queue Manager.

Alternatively, you can modify the `AUTHINFO` object `DEV.AUTHINFO` or create a new one and use this to specify what authentication you want to take place. But the way I understand your question ("to work without authentication"), the blank value is what you are looking for.

However, switching off authentication does not switch off authorization. As `MCAUSER` is blank in your channel definition, it will check authorization for the user which your client sends. As this one is not authenticated, there is no point to grant this specific user.

You can switch off authorizations entirely by defining environment variable `MQSNOAUTH` to `true` as described in the [MQ doc](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=umicpirho-deploying-queue-manager-onto-red-hat-openshift-container-platform-cluster).
Again, be aware of any reasonable warnings about this. And also note, that this does not work for Queue Managers which have already been created before.

If this works for you, you can stop here.

But if you don't want to switch off authorization entirely with `MQSNOAUTH`, than you can use the following approach to add authorization for all clients which want to connect via your unauthorized channel: Alter your channel definition to add a userId (with the name of your choice) and give this one the required authorizations (for MQ in containers there is no "mqm" super user).

Alter the channel def in `config.mqsc`:

```
DEFINE CHANNEL(MY.CHANNEL) +
   [...]
   MCAUSER('myuser') +
   [...]
```

Again `authentication.mqsc`:

```
ALTER QMGR CHLAUTH(DISABLED) CONNAUTH(' ')
REFRESH SECURITY TYPE(CONNAUTH)

SET AUTHREC OBJTYPE(QMGR) PRINCIPAL('myuser') AUTHADD(CONNECT,INQ)
SET AUTHREC PROFILE('MY.QUEUE') OBJTYPE(QUEUE) PRINCIPAL('myuser') AUTHADD(PUT,INQ,BROWSE,GET)
```

`AMQERR01.LOG` will tell you, if any authorization is missing.
To avoid the need to define a user `myuser` in your container, you can allow MQ to grant authorizations to non-os users. Add a file like `qm-service.ini` to your solution to update `qm.ini`:

```
Service:
   Name=AuthorizationService
   SecurityPolicy=UserExternal
```

By the way, you can continue to use this approach when you later on add authentication to your solution by defining an appropriate channel authentication record which overwrites MCAUSER by the authorized userId.

Comment: This is absolutely terrible advice and can lead to security breaches at your company. Never ever turn off security. The ONLY correct answer is to follow Morag advice in the other post.

Comment: This is absolutely terrible comment. You would be surprise to hear so many reasons why you want to do temporarily tests without user authentication. Even in production you may decide not to do user authentication by user/password check, but by certificates. I always appreciate any advice that security is a must, but when Noel93 asks for the right setup when he does not want userId/pw check, then we can expect that he knows that, well, user Id and password won't be checked.

Comment: Added a preface according to this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm aware that turning off security is a risk that should be avoided or at least handled carefully, but for my case, this has already been considered and won't be a problem here. That said, even when setting ```CONNAUTH(' ')```, I'm getting an error - I included the log in my question.

Comment: I have added hints for the authorization issue.

Comment: Thanks again. I added ```export MQSNOAUTH=yes``` in my ```setup.sh``` script before QMGR gets started. Checking ```DISPLAY QMGR AUTHOREV``` also returns ```AUTHOREV(DISABLED)``` but I'm still getting the same error...

Comment: Again, it only works if the environment variable is set when the Qmgr is created. To set it in your start script would be too late. Do you use persistent storage for your Qmgr data? In this case the Qmgr already exists after Container restarts and MQSNOAUT has no effect either.

Comment: I used the "better" solution of just giving authorization to my ```jboss``` principal. Your code gave me a syntax error until I deleted the 2nd ```INQ``` from the ```AUTHADD```, I'll edit your post accordingly. It's now working as intended, many thanks!

Comment: Right, there was a redundant INQ. I have just updated it. Glad to hear you were able to set the required authorization for your user.

Comment: Possibly it should be privilege of the one who found the error to do the update. I apologize if this is the case. :-)

Comment: No worries, I couldn't edit your post because of too many concurrent edits on SO or something. :)

Comment: @NineFriends There is never a valid reason to turn off security. Ever. What you have show this person and ALL future people who find this post, an "escape clause" to never do the right thing. It takes far less time to do it the right way than it is to do what you have suggested. I have worked with MQ since it was originally released & I have been a travelling consultant visiting many, many shops. Once security gets turned off, nobody ever goes back & turns it on again. Of course, at some point, rogue users (aka hackers) start stealing data because they can.

Comment: @Roger, “I have been x years in this topic” is not a point. You have 2 yrs more than myself. 2 yrs where there was even no such thing as MQ userId/pw check. You must have gone mad about it (I did), but good there were other options.
In a project, app business logic and security impl. may both have been designed prior but are implemented in parallel. On a developer PC there might be the need for an early MQ setup. This is just one valid example. All I did was to highlight things officially documented. And they are needed, they are valid. I did and do not recommend switching off security.

Comment: From the perspective of an advisor for the MQ team we want to say: do the right thing first. Still, impl. of the business logic may be started before the MQ team has finished setting up, say, an in-house CA or the LDAP access (successfully!). As soon as they have (prior to going live) it must be switched on also on any test env. I think we don’t disagree on the importance of security, but we should focus on the need of the one who asked the question, and I believe Noel93 is not member of the MQ staff in his org. Your comment helped that I added disclaimers to my answer as others are listening.

Answer (score 3):

The `JMSWMQ2013` error from JMS actually just means that the application received an MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED (2035) reason code from MQ. This reason code, deliberately, includes a number of possible failures. To convey the different failures to a client application would enhance the chances of a hacker being able to break in, so very little information is conveyed to the client.

To discover the specific reason for the failure, you must inspect the queue manager's `AMQERR01.LOG` file and see what it is complaining about.

You have correctly identified that CHLAUTH is one possibility, but there are numerous others, so take a look and see what it says. If you are unsure after reviewing the error log, please update your question with the error message details and further help will be provided.

You may find the following post useful in the mean time:-

- [Getting going without turning off IBM MQ Security](https://community.ibm.com/community/user/integration/viewdocument/from-the-archives-getting-going-wi)

Comment: Thanks, I've added the log to my initial post. Maybe I misunderstood "disabling authentication", because it seems like the user still needs to have some rights (e.g. "connect").